# How to set user permissions on an apple wiki server

Tags: security, permissions, apple, wiki

I'm looking for a some kind of a guide to setting permission on an apple wiki server.  I did a google search but I couldn't find much.  Anyone know of any guides or some quick instructions?

Cheers.

Comment: Why would configuring security on a wiki server be something to vote to close?

Answer (score 0):

The server setup guide ([here](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Wiki_Server_Admin_v10.6.pdf)) under wiki security didn't have what you were looking for?